# Add alert DIV to validation script (jquery / javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, alert

I have a validation script (calling out its parent script) that I would like to change.

I would like to display a hidden DIV as an alert above the form *when an error is found*.

**Is there a way to add this to my existing script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    $('#rbSubmit').formValidator({
        scope: '#form_register',
            onError: function () {
            if ($('#input_1 input').hasClass('error-input')) {
                $('#r1 div, #r1 input').css('background-color', '#C1272D').css('color', '#FFF');
            } else {
                $('#r1 div').css('background-color', '#E8E8E8');
            }
            if ($('#input_1 input').hasClass('error-input')) {
                $("#r1 .ts").css("background-position", "-928px -318px");
            } else {
                $('#r1 div').css('background-color', '#E8E8E8');
            }
            if ($('#input_2 input').hasClass('error-input')) {
                $('#r2 div, #r2 input').css('background-color', '#C1272D').css('color', '#FFF');
            } else {
                $('#r2 div').css('background-color', '#E8E8E8');
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Define an empty div in your form eg.

1. Use $("#divError).html("error statement");

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Hopefully this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Create the `DIV` with `style="display:none"`.  I'll assume the div has ID of `error_div`.

When an error is encountered, do `$("#error_div").show();`

If you need to add messages do the DIV, you can do so with `$("#error_div").text("error in input 2");`